# Objective-C autorelease memory management

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to understand when to call autorelease, and what this will actually do to my object.

After reading [*About Memory Management*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)) in the Mac Developer Library I understood that when you have a method that acts as a factory method - by creating a new object and returning it - the method has no way of releasing the object before returning it, because this would result in a deallocted object being returned.

**Example**

```
- (Test *) createNewTest 
{
    Test *newInstance = [[Test alloc] init];
    [newInstance release];
    return newInstance; // deallocted object returned.
}
```

Instead I should use `autorelease`:

> The autorelease method, defined by NSObject, marks the receiver for later release

My question is: if the object is to be released later, how do I know when its being released?

```
- (Test *) createNewTest 
{
    Test *newInstance = [[test alloc] init];
    [newInstance autorelease];
    return newInstance;
}

- (void) runIt
{
    Test *myInstance = [self createNewTest];
    // when is myInstance released?? and thereby not valid to my function anymore?
}
```

How can I safely use the returned autoreleased object inside my `runIt` method if I don't know when the autorelease happens? Should I retain the object returned by the `createNewTest`? Or can I safely use it within the `runIt` scope?

Comment: btw - by obj-c naming guidelines your createNewTest method should return non-autoreleased object as it contains 'new' in its name.

Comment: the object is instantiated with an alloc, and so it has to be released.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An autoreleased object is added to an autorelease pool.

Objects in the autorelease pool are released at the end of an iteration of the main runloop (or sooner if you are managing your own autorelease pool and/or if you call drain).

When you call a method that returns an autoreleased object, it is pretty much guaranteed to stay valid until at least the end of the scope that it was called in.

If you want to ensure that it stays alive longer then you should retain it, remembering to release it again when you're finished with it.

Comment: you say "pretty much guaranteed" is it best practice to retain and release in the method calling the factory method?.

Comment: The object will stay valid for its scope. You can retain/release if you want that 100% piece of mind.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) i just have one more question, what if runIt() would return the object created would the method calling runIt() have a safe object aswell :) ?

Comment: Yes, as the returned object would be in the scope of the caller.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i safely use the returned
>   autoreleased object inside my runIt
>   method if i dont know when the
>   autorelease trigger?

Autorelease will trigger after the current run loop ends.

> Should i retain the object returned by
>   the createNewTest ? or can i safely
>   use it within the runIt scope?

You can safely use it inside the runIt scope.

Answer (score -1):

The one responsible for creating it and the one who calls runIt has to retain the object. When the one responsible is done with it, it should then release the object.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to retain the object and release it after the use.