# Remove memory leak due to returning the variable created

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

Follwing is my code snippet In which I am getting memory leak issues.
[image]

This is the warning number 3.

**Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'strRespondData' is returned from a method whose name ('httpConnection:postStr:') does not start with 'copy', 'mutableCopy', 'alloc' or 'new'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa**

*My code is ARC enabled.

Comment: Judging from the error ("+1 retain count" text), ARC isn't enabled. Maybe you have it disabled specifically for this file with `-fno-objc-arc` flag?

Comment: try `return [strRespondData mutableCopy];`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I aam still getting the warnings 1 & 2 with mutablecopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use autorelease message:

```
NSString *strRespondData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

You can read explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192308/objective-c-autorelease-memory-management)

If you use ARC you no need to worry about it, ARC will handle this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Release this line

```
NSString *strRespondData = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
```

with this conversion and try.

```
NSString* strRespondData = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
```

Answer (score 1):

the **warning message** says your method's name violates the naming convention of memory management guideline

**> does not start with 'copy', 'mutableCopy', 'alloc' or 'new'**

your code is valid under ARC